# A fixed div that stays within its parent's width?

Tags: html, css, css-position

Here's a simplified version of my homepage:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="content"> all the content of my website </div>
    <div class="nav"> fixed on the screen and always visible </div>
</div>
```

And here's the corresponding css:

```
.main {
    max-width: 500px;
    height: 2000px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: grey;
}

.nav {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    position:fixed;
    right: 0; /* that's the issue */
}
```

I'd like the fixed element to stay within it's parent (touching the right edge of its parent). But right now it's touching the right border of the screen.

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Just use a float right instead of a position?

Comment: But I do want the div to be fixed, so it's always visible on the screen even when I scroll.

Comment: you would need to use a bit of javascript for this and absolute positioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an extra item to simulate the properties of the main container, try this:

```css
.main {
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 2000px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: grey;
}
.nav {
  position:fixed;
  max-width:500px;
  width:100%;
}
.nav > div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  float:right;  
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="content">all the content of my website</div>
  <div class="nav"><div>fixed on the screen and always visible</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`position: fixed` is described as, "The element is positioned relative to the browser window". You can use Javascript to accomplish this effect, here is how you do it with jQuery, for example:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
            var y = $(window).scrollTop();
            $(".nav").css('top', y);
});
```

```css
.main {
    max-width: 500px;
    height: 4000px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: grey;
    position: relative;
}

.nav {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0; /* that's the issue */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="content"> parent </div>
    <div class="nav"> fixed to parent width </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do want the div to be fixed so it's always visible on the screen even when I scroll.

Comment: DaniP has a really good solution, the only consideration on that is that if you vary the width of the parent item, you also have to update the value on the `.nav` max-width property.

Comment: for Div css use position: fixed